# Adding Jetty bundles to Eclipse RCP target causes other bundles to be removed

Tags: jetty, eclipse-rcp, p2, target-platform

I have an RCP app that uses the Jetty WebSocket client. I created a plug-in that wraps the jetty websocket client code, along with the other jetty dependencies, and this works.

Now I want to include jetty in my RCP target instead of using the plug-in that wraps the jetty code. I add a location to my target pointing to the [jetty update site](https://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/), select the desired version of jetty, and leave unchecked the option "include required software". The target seems to load successfully, but some plugins that used to appear in the target disappear.

For example, before adding the jetty location, on the content tab when I filter for xtend, I see bundle org.eclipse.xtend, which was loaded from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna. After adding the jetty location, the bundle org.eclispe.xtend is no longer seen on the content tab. Both before and after adding the jetty location, in the target editor UI I have various features selected for the luna releases location, including the EMF SDK, EMF Xcore SDK, and four Graphiti features. Nothing was changed in the UI, so I don't understand why simply adding a location pointing to the jetty update site makes bundles go away in other locations.

I tried editing the target source file, just adding the jetty location and bumping the sequence counter at the top of the file, and I get the same result. I also tried explicitly adding the XTend feature in the luna releases location, also to no avail.

This is just one example of a plugin that goes missing. There are a few more that also disappear. It seems that the mere fact of adding a location pointing to the jetty update site renders my target unusable.

Can anyone share any examples of how to add jetty to an RCP target?

edit: Target files before and after adding a location pointing to jetty

before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="com.example.target" sequenceNumber="14">
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group" version="8.6.0.201502131403"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.sdk.feature.group" version="8.6.0.201502131403"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.gef.sdk.feature.group" version="3.9.101.201408150207"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.4.2.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.tcf.te.terminals.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.201406042322"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.tcf.te.terminals.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.201406042322"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/tcf/terminals_luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="com.google.gson" version="2.2.4.v201311231704"/>
<unit id="com.google.gson.source" version="2.2.4.v201311231704"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.export.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.sdk.plus.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.sdk.feature.group" version="1.2.2.v20150202-0452"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.10.2.v20150123-0452"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.tools.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.zest.sdk.feature.group" version="1.5.101.201408150207"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group" version="4.1.0.201505270003"/>
<repository location="http://pydev.org/updates"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>
```

after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="com.example.target" sequenceNumber="15">
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group" version="8.6.0.201502131403"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.sdk.feature.group" version="8.6.0.201502131403"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.gef.sdk.feature.group" version="3.9.101.201408150207"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.4.2.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.tcf.te.terminals.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.201406042322"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.tcf.te.terminals.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.201406042322"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/tcf/terminals_luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="com.google.gson" version="2.2.4.v201311231704"/>
<unit id="com.google.gson.source" version="2.2.4.v201311231704"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.export.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.sdk.plus.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.sdk.feature.group" version="1.2.2.v20150202-0452"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.10.2.v20150123-0452"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.tools.feature.group" version="0.11.2.v20150204-0954"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.zest.sdk.feature.group" version="1.5.101.201408150207"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group" version="4.1.0.201505270003"/>
<repository location="http://pydev.org/updates"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.jetty.bundles.f.feature.group" version="9.2.5.201411141551"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>
```

Comment: Could you share your target file?

Comment: I added before and after target files to the post.

Comment: I found the source of the problem. The target editor changed includeMode from "planner" to "slicer" for each location. I noticed this before and changed it back, and it didn't help. But I neglected to do the "eclipse dance" after making this change, which is often required when making a change to an RCP target.

This was an issue with the target editor, and not related to jetty apparently, as I re-produced the problem by adding any location to an existing target.

Comment: The specific dance steps that worked are: 1) Save target file 2) Delete target from Window->Preferences->Plug-in Development->Target Platform 3) re-start eclipse with -clean 4) Import saved target file 5) Set as current target platform.

Comment: Yes the editor offers only one Option for all sites. If you use a Text editor you can change it. But you cannot use the UI-based editor anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if that's a feature or a bug? Given that eclipse p2 sites on the web don't let you navigate the repo with a web browser, it seems going without the UI is more than a minor inconvenience. I don't know of any other way to determine feature IDs and available versions for update sites. And any time I use the UI to make a change, it requires removing the target as I described. It seems it stays in planner mode even when I change to slicer and update the sequence number. Only removing the target and re-creating it enables it to respect what's in the text file after using the UI.

Comment: You can try to switch to Eclipse Mars which comes with Oomph Targlets. These allow you to specify version or version ranges and specific IUs per repo site. In addition there is a repository browser view, which allows you to investigate p2 repo contents.

Comment: I'll try Mars on Monday. But to be clear on the behavior in Luna, further work yesterday seemed to demonstrate that even when editing the target file in a text editor, if I have one or more locations in slicer mode, then all locations operate in slicer mode, even if set to planner. I might have misunderstood, but I thought you were saying this would only happen if I used the GUI editor. Anyway, thanks for the tip on Mars and Oomph.